# Getting rid of "The publisher could not be verified" for a SINGLE instance install - Possible?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, code-signing

I have a Windows Forms (C#, SQL Server) application that I developed up and running and all is well, except for when I try to run its `Release` .exe **on my own development workstation**, it issues the *"The publisher could not be verified"* warning.

(When I run this application from Visual Studio in `Debug` mode, I don't get this warning)

I know about [code signing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1427930/1731850) but this application is going to be installed on a **single machine** only (directly by me, on the client's machine), so I am thinking perhaps there is a way to get rid of this warning without having to sign the EXE, similar to the exception Microsoft does when running from Visual Studio?

Note: on a single install single machine only.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are your running it from a network share by any chance?

If so, try copying it to a `C:\` folder and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Copying the release .exe to `C:\Users\me\Documents` magically solved the problem. I didn't know that code signing certificate is not checked if the application is on a local drive. Thanks!