# how can I add my publisher name into my delphi exe program?

Tags: delphi, exe

I do develop delphi programs that people do download.
Problem is when downloading them, they receieve an alert

"The publisher cannot be verified."

How can I add my publisher name into my delphi programs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a code-signing certificate, and need to digitally sign your executable using that certificate.

Search for `[windows] code signing` here at StackOverflow.  There are tons of questions here on the topic; any and all of them (regardless of language used) for Windows applications apply to Delphi as well. [Here is a start for you.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/252226/62576), and [here's another one with links to resources](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1427768/62576). (Both links are here at StackOverflow, and not external sites.)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I created a test certificate for my setup executable (produced by Inno Setup).

I used:

```
makecert -r -pe -ss MyCertStore -n "CN=MyTestCert" MyTestCert.cer
signtool sign /s MyCertStore /n MyTestCert  MyApplication.exe
```

I could find these tools under:

"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\"

Dont forget to install *MyTestCert.cer* under trusted providers, otherwise the *MyApplication.exe* will still show unknown publisher. Check with *certmgr.exe* which I could find in the same folder.

Worked for me on Win7x64.

For final signing you need a commercial code signing certificate, the cheapest I could find was from Comodo (about $70 a year).